# replacing blank strings with count

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Let's say I have a list like this:

```
py = ['','','','','monty','','','','python',]
```

and I want to map it to this:

```
[4,'monty',3,'python']
```

Does anyone know a clever solution?  I was able to figure this out to convert it to this:

```
[1,1,1,1,'monty',1,1,1,'python',]
```

using:

```
quotes = [x if x else 1 for x in quotes]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Code:**

```
def convert_quote_list(input_list):
    quotes = [x if x else 1 for x in input_list]

    counter = 0
    ans = []
    for each in quotes:
        if each == 1:
            counter += 1
        else:
            if counter:
                ans.append(counter)
            ans.append(each)
            counter = 0
    return ans

convert_quote_list(['','','','','monty','','','','python',])
convert_quote_list(['monty','','','python',])
```

**Output:**

```
[4, 'monty', 3, 'python']
['monty', 2, 'python']
```

Comment: check this `['monty', '', '', 'python'']`

Answer (score 1):

```
py = ['','','','','monty','','','','python']
py2 = ['','','','','monty','','','','python', '', '', '']

def conv(lst):
    out = []
    count = 0
    for s in lst:
        if s == '': count += 1
        else:
            if count > 0:
                out.append(count)
            count = 0
            out.append(s)
    if count > 0: out.append(count)

    return out

print(conv(py))
print(conv(py2))
```

Output

```
[4, 'monty', 3, 'python']  
[4, 'monty', 3, 'python', 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think [Rob's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33335999/1113207) is the best: most readable and most easy to understand. I fixed it for case last element is blank and changed to work as generator (it would be more effective then using `append`):

```
def blank_to_count(iterable):
    counter = 0
    for val in iterable:
        if val == '':
            counter += 1
        else:
            if counter > 0: yield counter  # yield count of blank elements
            counter = 0
            yield val  # yield current non-blank element
    if counter > 0: yield counter  # in case last element was blank

py = ['','','','','monty','','','','python',]
print(list(blank_to_count(py)))  # [4, 'monty', 3, 'python']

py = ['monty','','','','python']
print(list(blank_to_count(py)))  # ['monty', 3, 'python']

py = ['','','','','monty','','','','python','','']
print(list(blank_to_count(py)))  # [4, 'monty', 3, 'python', 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use python's [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to create a list of iterators  grouped by the value in the list. Then using list comprehension and short circuit evaluation, get either the length of the list of iterator or the string value

```
import itertools

py = ['','','','','monty','','','','python',]
out = [(k == 1 and len(list(v))) or k for k, v in (grp for grp in itertools.groupby(py, lambda x: x or 1))]
print out
[4, 'monty', 3, 'python']
```

EDIT: Upon reflection, the code might be hard to read so you can do this instead:

```
import itertools

out = []

for k, v in itertools.groupby(py, lambda x: x or 1):
    if k == 1:
        out.append(len(list(v)))
    else:
        out.append(k)

print out
```